# conditional properties

Tags: c#, properties

I have a base class (Node) and some inherited types.

```
Class Node
{
    Base_Attributes...
}

Class Derived : Node
{
    Derived_Attributes...
}
```

These types are in a dll I've added to my project. And there is a class let's say Item that one of its attributes is Node. I have a Propertygrid in which I display itme's properties like this:

```
Class Item
{
Point location;
String name;
Node quiddity;

bool[] IsBrowsable;

public Point Location{set;get;}
public String Name{set;get;}
public String NodeAttrib{set;get;}
[Browsable(IsBrowsable[thisindex])]
public String DerivedTypeAttribe{set;get;}
[Browsable(IsBrowsable[otheroneindex])]
public String DerivedTypeAttribe{set;get;}

Item(string type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case"some":
            Node = new derived_some();
            IsBrowsable[thisindex] = true;
            break;
    }
}
}
```

and somewhere in mainform:

```
propertygrid.selectedobject = item;
```

The problem here is there's some properties specified to derived types and I need to show them in the propetygrid but the type of node is not known till in run-time. I tried to set Browsabl() attribute using an array of booleans but turned out Browsable Parameter needs to be a constant value. Any ideas how could I pass this ?

Comment: Haven't got time to go into it in full, but it you really want you can do this with either TypeConverter or (more complex) ICustomTypeDescriptior. Usually inheriting ExpandableTypeConverter and overriding GetProperties (and filtering as appropriate) is enough.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would you please give more details how could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of filtering via `TypeDescriptor`; you can of course change the "how do I know which properties to show" code - this is purely illustrative:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        PropertyGrid grid;
        using (var form = new Form
        {
            Controls = { (grid = new PropertyGrid { Dock = DockStyle.Fill}) }
        })
        {
            grid.SelectedObject = new Magic {ShowY = false};
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(MagicTypeConverter))]
public class Magic
{
    public Magic()
    {
        ShowX = ShowY = ShowZ = true;
    }

    public int A { get; set; }
    public bool B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public bool Y { get; set; }
    public string Z { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public bool ShowX { get; set; }
    [Browsable(false)]
    public bool ShowY { get; set; }
    [Browsable(false)]
    public bool ShowZ { get; set; }

    private class MagicTypeConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
    {
        public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(
             ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value,
             Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            var original = base.GetProperties(context, value, attributes);
            var list = new List<PropertyDescriptor>(original.Count);
            var magic = (Magic)value;
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in original)
            {
                bool showProp = true;
                switch (prop.Name)
                {
                    case "X": showProp = magic.ShowX; break;
                    case "Y": showProp = magic.ShowY; break;
                    case "Z": showProp = magic.ShowZ; break;
                }
                if (showProp) list.Add(prop);
            }
            return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(list.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It was really illustrative and made it work just fine.